# combinatorics- persons in group

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Let $$ n = \binom {k + b-2}{k-1} \text{ and  }k, b\ge 2 $$ Prove that in each group of at least n persons there is k person is familiar with everybody or there are b persons two did not know each other.

Comment: Do you have any additional information? Say under what condition a person with be familiar with others?

Comment: "b persons two" , is it "b persons of two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(k,b)$ be the assertion in the problem. Suppose that $P(k-1,b)$ and $P(k,b-1)$ are true, and let $S$ be a set of

$$n=\binom{k+n-2}{k-1}=\binom{k+n-3}{k-2}+\binom{k+n-3}{k-1}$$

people. Fix $p\in S$, and let $S_0=S\setminus\{p\}$. Let $S_1$ be the set of people in $S_0$ whom $p$ knows, and let $S_2=S_0\setminus S_1$. Then

$$|S_1|\ge\binom{k+b-3}{k-2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad|S_2|\ge\binom{k+b-3}{k-1}\;.$$

If $|S_1|\ge\binom{k+b-3}{k-2}$, either there are $b$ members of $S_1$ who are mutual strangers, or there are $k-1$ members of $S_1$ who know one another, and those $k-1$ together with $p$ form a set of $k$ who know one another. If $|S_2|>\binom{k+b-3}{k-1}$, either there are $k$ members of $S_2$ who know one another, or there are $b-1$ who are mutual strangers, and together with $p$ they form a set of $b$ mutual strangers. Thus, $S$ contains either a set of $k$ mutual acquaintances or a set of $b$ mutual strangers, and $P(k,b)$ holds.

$P(2,2)$ is clearly true, and it’s also clear that for any $k$ and $b$, $P(k,b)$ holds if and only if $P(b,k)$ holds. The statement of the problem disallows $P(1,2)$ and $P(2,1)$, but there’s no good reason for this, and the statements are true, since a set of one person is rather vacuously both a set of mutual acquaintances and a set of mutual strangers. (A set fails to be either of these if and only if it contains two people who know each other **and** two people who don’t, and this is certainly not the case for a singleton set.) In fact, $P(n,1)$ and $P(1,n)$ are similarly true for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

The result now follows by induction on $k+b$. Suppose that $m\ge 3$, and $P(k,b)$ holds for all $k,b\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $k+b<m$. We just saw that $P(m-1,1)$ and $P(1,m-1)$ hold. By the argument given above, $P(m-b,b)$ follows from $P(m-b-1,b)$ and $P(m-b-1,b-1)$ for $2\le b\le m-2$, which hold by the induction hypothesis, so $P(k,b)$ holds for all $k,b\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $k+b=m$.

This problem is essentially the [two-color case of Ramsey’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't understand that:
If $|S1|≥ \binom {k+b-3}{k-2} $...
please help me.

Comment: @user180834: That’s just the induction hypotheses applied to $S_1$: $P(k-1,b)$ says that in a group of at least $$\binom{(k-1)+b-2}{(k-1)-1}=\binom{k+b-3}{k-2}$$ there are either $k-1$ mutual acquaintances or $b$ mutual strangers. If there are $b$ mutual strangers, we have what we want. Otherwise we take the $k-1$ mutual acquaintances and note that they all know $p$, so we have our $k$ mutual acquaintances. The rest of the paragraph is the same idea, but applying $P(k,b-1)$ to $S_2$ instead.

Comment: I don't understand why there are k-1 MUTUAL friends if there is no b mutual strangers.

Comment: @user180834: I may have misunderstood the question. I understood you to mean that the $k$ people were all familiar with one another. If you really meant $k$ people who are familiar with everybody in the whole group, the statement is false for $k=2,b=3$: $\binom{2+3-2}{2-1}=3$, but if the people are A, B, and C, and only A and B know each other, then no one knows everybody, and there are not $3$ mutual strangers. There *are*, however, $2$ people who are mutual acquaintances, namely A and B.

Comment: No, no, no:
k person should be familiar with everybody in THIS GROUP.
Example: k = 3. Let persons be A B C 
And now the A must know B and C, B must know A and C and C must know A and B

Comment: @user180834: Good: that’s how I interpreted it in my answer. Those $3$ people are mutual friends.

Comment: Ok, probably I'm make a mistake, but:
You claim that  $k=2,b=3: $ break assertion. 
Consider that again
$k=2,b=3: \binom {2+3−2} {2−1} =3 $, but if the people are A, B, and C, and only A and B know each other.
And that satisfy the conditions of task. k =2 so it must be two mutual acquaintance, and indeed it is. ( A and B )

Comment: @user180834: I do not make that claim for the problem as you actually meant it. When you made your ‘I don’t understand why’ comment, I thought that I might have misinterpreted the problem. I suggested a different interpretation, one that (as it turned out) you did **not** mean, and showed that **that** interpretation would make the result false if $k=2$ and $b=3$. The problem as you intended it is fine, and the result does hold for $k=2$ and $b=3$.

Comment: In any case,thanks a lot for your time! :)

Comment: @user180834: Let’s back up and start over: ignore everything after your *I don’t understand why* comment. Look at my comment before that one: the induction hypothesis $P(k-1,b)$ says that either there are $k-1$ mutual acquaintances, or there are $b$ mutual strangers. Thus, if there aren’t $b$ mutual strangers, there *must* be $k-1$ mutual acquaintances. It’s strictly an application of $P(k-1,b)$ to the set $S_1$, which is big enough for $P(k-1,b)$ to apply to it.